# Word for a person who is overly profound?

Tags: word-choice

Dramatic somewhat fits my word choice. However, a person can be dramatic without being profound.

Comment: A bit of context would really be helpful here.

Comment: I find it difficult to imagine a situation where profundity might cause a problem; Some context would definitely be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Someone whose walk does not live up to their talk could be called [**pretentious**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pretentious?s=t).

Comment: The ostentatiously profound are an annoying species.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Better or worse than the profoundly ostentatious?

Answer (score 0):

**[Ham](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ham)** an actor or performer who overacts.

**[Grandstander](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grandstander)**: One who grandstands, conducts oneself or performs showily or ostentatiously in an attempt to impress onlookers.

Answer (score 0):

[**histrionic**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/histrionic) would fit.

> deliberately affected or self-consciously emotional; overly dramatic in behavior or speech.

Though a context would be better because there can be numerous words to list and none of them would fit exactly.

Comment: @DavidM -- that's a more sophisticate version of the complaint against "niggardly". "Hysteria" comes ultimately from *ὑστέρα* (*hustera*), "uterus", via the superstition that emotional difficulties derive from uterine problems. Some women take offense at the word, and suggesting that they are becoming hysterical on the issue is surprisingly unhelpful.  "Histrionic" is unrelated and comes from *histriō*, "actor".

Comment: Sorry. For some reason I read it as hysterical. Which is doubly stupid since it doesn't even fit the context. That's what I get for reading on my phone while walking into the gym.  Niggardly still makes me blush to say it aloud, but that's just collateral damage so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term **deep** to describe them.  It works with both positive and negative connotations and someone who is profound is definitely deep.

> I live by this [deep thought](http://www.babson.us/quotes/deep_thoughts.html):
>
> The first thing was, I learned to
>   forgive myself. Then, I told myself, "Go ahead and do whatever you
>   want, it's okay by me."